# what is these methods "with" and "and" in java?

Tags: java, jpa, methods, keyword

I am reviewing a new project code. I found the following line:

```
 crudService.findByNamedQueryFirstResult("TableA.findby.custid", with(
                "custID", IndividulaID).and("flags", custflags).parameters())
```

I don't see methods "with" and "and" in any class. And its not string concatenation.
I know a JPQ query has with and and. But how is it possible to pass params like above?

Can someone help?

Comment: You can tell they aren't keywords as they need parameters.  So these are methods.  They are probably defined in the same jar as the crudservice.

Comment: also, check for [static imports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `with` or `and` keywords in Java. Those are method calls.

Here, the `with()` method is imported via a static import (see @damo's comment) and creates an instance of a builder class; the `and()` method is a method which returns `this`; the `.parameters()` class will then build the class, and return what the calling method actually needs. This is a classical builder pattern.

Static imports can be used to great readability effects. Consider mockito. Either you write:

```
Mockito.when(xxx).then(xxx);
```

or:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

// the compiler know where `when()` comes from
when(xxx).then(xxx);
```

The generic pattern for such constructs is called a **fluent interface**. To complete the answer, I'd just point to what I have done for one of my projects:

```
ProcessorSelector<IN, OUT> selector = new ProcessorSelector<IN, OUT>();

selector = selector.when(predicate1).then(p1)
    .when(predicate2).then(p2)
    .otherwise(defaultProcessor);

final Processor<IN, OUT> processor = selector.getProcessor();
```

The `ProcessorSelector` class has a `when()` method; this method returns *another class* on which there is a `then()` method; and the `then()` method returns, again, a `ProcessorSelector`, which has `when()`, etc. Finally, the `otherwise()` method returns a `ProcessorSelector` on which you have a `.getProcessor()` returning a `Processor`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a fluent-api (see http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-fluent-api-designer-crash for general definition)

In your case it may be spring-jpa, QueryDSL or similar framework.

To identify the API, you should have a look at the type/superclass/interfaces of **crudService** as well as the definitions of with/and/parameters.